# Mockito UnfinishedStubbingException when mocking multiple times

Tags: java, mockito, stub, spy

I want to stub the methot *generateReferenceNumber()* in my Invoice class :

```
public class Invoice {

    private String id;
    private String referenceNumber;
    private Date issueDate;
    private PaymentMethod paymentMethod;
    private Date paymentDate;
    private String shopId;
    private List<InvoiceGroupItem> groupItems;
    private InvoiceStatus status;

    public void moveToNextState() {
        status = status.nextState();
    }

    public void generateReferenceNumber() {
        if (referenceNumber != null) {
            return;
        }

        referenceNumber = new InvoiceReference().createNew(issueDate).toString();
    }
}
```

This object is used in a service which I want to test. For that purpose I need multiple Invoices. So I wrote de following code :

```
private Stream<Invoice> buildApprovedInvoice() {
    val approvedInvoices = new ArrayList<Invoice>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        val invoice = Invoice.builder().build();
        val spy = spy(invoice);

        doAnswer(invocation -> {
            final Invoice mock = (Invoice) invocation.getMock();
            mock.setReferenceNumber("Invoice reference number");
            return null;
        }).when(spy).generateReferenceNumber();

        approvedInvoices.add(spy);
    }

    return approvedInvoices.stream();
}
```

And when I execute the test, I get the following error :

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
>   Unfinished stubbing detected here:
>   -> at com.coruscant.core.services.invoice.InvoiceSendingServiceTest.sendInvoices(InvoiceSendingServiceTest.java:54)
>
> E.g. thenReturn() may be missing. Examples of correct stubbing:
>       when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
>       when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
>       doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();

Anyone has an idea why ?

Thank you.

Comment: I am pretty sure the exception is not coming from the code that is displayed in your question. Can you provide a [mre] that produces the exception?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mock `Invoice` for testing it. Or you can mock `InvoiceReference` if it is unit test. If it is integration test:

```
class Test {

   private Invoice invoice;

   @BeforeEach
   void setUp() {
      invoice - new Invoice();
   }
   @Test
   void shouldSetReferenceNumber_WhenReferenceNumberEqualsNull() {
      invoice.setIssueDate(new Date());
      invoice.generateReferenceNumber();
      assertThat(invoice).hasFieldWithValue("referenceNumber", expectingValue);
   }

   @Test
   void shouldNotSetReferenceNumber_WhenReferenceNumberIsNotEqualsNull() {
      invoice.setReferenceNumber("test-reference-number");
      invoice.generateReferenceNumber();
      assertThat(invoice).hasFieldWithValue("referenceNumber", "test-reference-number");
   }
}
```

Unit test(mock InvoiceReference):

```
public class Invoice {

    private String id;
    private String referenceNumber;
    private Date issueDate;
    private PaymentMethod paymentMethod;
    private Date paymentDate;
    private String shopId;
    private List<InvoiceGroupItem> groupItems;
    private InvoiceStatus status;

    public void moveToNextState() {
        status = status.nextState();
    }

    public void generateReferenceNumber() {
        if (referenceNumber != null) {
            return;
        }

        getInvoiceReference().createNew(issueDate).toString(); 
    }

   public InvoiceReference getInvoiceReference() {
      return new InvoiceReference();
   }
}

class Test {

   private Invoice invoice;
   @Mock
   private InvoiceReference invoiceReference;

   @BeforeEach
   void setUp() {
      invoice = new Invoice();
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
      when(invoiceReference.createNew(any(Date.class)).thenReturn("test-reference-number");
   }

   @Test
   void shouldSetReferenceNumber_WhenReferenceNumberEqualsNull() {
      invoice.setIssueDate(new Date());
      invoice.generateReferenceNumber();
      assertThat(invoice).hasFieldWithValue("referenceNumber", "test-reference-number");
   }

   @Test
   void shouldNotSetReferenceNumber_WhenReferenceNumberIsNotEqualsNull() {
      invoice.setReferenceNumber("different_reference_number");
      invoice.generateReferenceNumber();
      assertThat(invoice).hasFieldWithValue("referenceNumber", "different_reference_number");
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't really know how to just mock InvoiceReference as I am calling new InvoiceReference().
Can you explain ?

Comment: Mmm I see but I can of don't really like to have to build an InvoiceReference getter.
My post was more about why my utilisation of Mockito's doAnswer() is incorrect.

But thanks for the help.

Comment: Alexandre Liscia then just use first solution(without mocking InvoiceReference)

Comment: Can you provide an explanation on why this doesn't work ?
And more, I don't want to test Invoice but a service which uses it.